# How to provide the output of the first input file as the second input file in one pass in C?

Tags: c, file, file-io, lex, file-handling

Assume that I have a file called 1.lex. An input file 1.c is provided. The output of this is the next input. I want this to happen in a single pass because when the first output is produced, the memory buffer contains some information that is required for the second input file.

Below is the code for file handling for the situation explained above.

```
char * basename(char *name)
{
        char *temp;
        int i=0, j=0, len;

        temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(name));
        len = strlen(name);
        len--;
        while(1)
        {
                if(name[len] != '.')
                        len--;
                else
                {
                        for( i = 0; i < len; i++)
                                temp[j++] = name[i];
                        break;
                }
        }
        temp[j] = '\0';
        return temp;
    }





    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
            if(argc != 2)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: filename\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
            if(yyin == NULL)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr,"cannot open file: %s",argv[1]);
                    exit(0);
            }

            file = basename(argv[1]);
            realloc(file, strlen(file)+10);
            strcat(file,".met");
            yyout = fopen(file,"w");
            yyparse();
            return 0;
    }

    int yywrap()
    {
            fclose(yyin);
            yyin = fopen(file,"r");
            if(yyin == NULL)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr,"cannot open file: %s",file);
                    exit(0);
            }
            file = basename(file);
            realloc(file, strlen(file)+10);
            strcat(file,".meta");
            yyout = fopen(file,"w");
            yyparse(); 
            return 1;
    }
```

If I comment yyparse() in yywrap() function, there is no segmentation fault but nothing gets written in ".meta" file but first o/p file ".met" gets written. If I uncomment, there is segmentation fault and nothing gets written in ".met" file.

Function "basename" is to get the basename of the input.

Function main() which opens the first file and calls yyparse().

When yyparse() is finished with the first file, it calls yywrap(), which opens the next file.

Please see the comment above in the yyparse() line.

If there is another way to solve my problem, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you are going to want `temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(name)+1);`

Comment: Thanks chux for the reply. Why and where would I want that? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Can't elaborate as it appears you are OK on that point.  Nit: `len` is a problem if `name` is unusually short as in "", but then an argv[1] would need to be "".  Hmmmm, Wonder if that is possible?  ProgramName "" maybe?

Comment: Hey Chux, I solved the problem. Just did a workaround. Strange. Got the answer though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the code posted initially. I have explained the changes after the code.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        file_num++;
        argc = file_num_max;
        if(argc != 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"Usage: filename\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if(yyin == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"cannot open file: %s",argv[1]);
                exit(0);
        }

        file = basename(argv[1]);
        realloc(file, strlen(file)+10);
        strcat(file,".met");
        yyout = fopen(file,"w");
        while(yylex())
                ;
        return 0;
}

int yywrap()
{
        fclose(yyin);
        fclose(yyout);
        yyin = fopen(file,"r");
        if(++file_num <= file_num_max)
        {
        if(yyin == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"cannot open file: %s",file);
                exit(0);
        }
        file = basename(file);
        realloc(file, strlen(file)+10);
        strcat(file,".meta");
        yyout = fopen(file,"w");
        return 0;
        } else {
        return 1;
        }
}
```

As said before, function main() which opens the first file and calls yylex().

When yylex() is finished with the first file, it calls yywrap(), which opens the next file, and yylex() continues.

When yywrap() has exhausted all the command line arguments, it returns 1, and yylex().

I just did some small changes and it worked but took some time though!

Cheers.

Comment: I spent time and efforts to guide you towards a solution to finally be stripped off the humble gratification we can get out of this site. Do you think this is ethical?

Answer (score 1):

Create a pipe and open it for writing and assign it to yyout and open the pipe for reading and assign it to yyin
See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link and reply. Will let you know if it works or not. Hope it works with lex. Thanks again.

Comment: Take care of looking for platform specific documentation.

Comment: I didn't use the pipes but I did a workaround with my code. It's working now. It can also be done using pipes. Similar approach though. Thanks again. It's marked.

Comment: I am curious to find out the other alternative. Maybe you could post it as an answer for the general benefit.

Comment: Hey Tarik, I have posted it. Thanks mate. Cheers.